# Issue with pdf package MultiPage: Exception when dynamically adding pages

Tags: flutter, dart-pdf

I'm currently facing a bug while working with the pdf package in Flutter. I'm using the MultiPage widget to create a PDF document and dynamically add new pages when the content overflows. The package is designed to create new pages automatically, but I'm encountering an error that I can't seem to resolve.

To explain the issue further, when I add the same widget, it correctly creates page 1. When I add more of the same widget, it creates page 2 as expected. However, when I continue adding widgets, instead of creating page 3, I receive an exception.

> _Exception (Exception: This widget created more than 50 pages. This may be an issue in the widget or the document. See https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf/latest/widgets/MultiPage-class.html)

I've followed the documentation and guidelines for the MultiPage class, but I can't seem to resolve this issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem or found a workaround for it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance

```
  Future<void> generate() async {
final logo = await _logo();
final pdf = pw.Document();
pdf.addPage(pw.MultiPage(
  pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
  maxPages: 50,
  build: (pw.Context context) {
    return [
      pw.Column(
        children: [
          pw.Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              logo,
              pw.Text(
                Texts.title.toUpperCase(),
                textAlign: pw.TextAlign.center,
                style: pw.TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: pw.FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          _buildTableDadosTransformador(),
          _buildTablePotencia(),
          _buildTableNucleo(),
          _buildTablePrimario(),
          _buildTableSecundarios(),
        ],
      )
    ];
  },
));
savePDF(pdf);
```

}

Comment: The problem was that I had a Column that was exceeding the page size! The solution was to separate this Column, which contained a dynamically created table, and split each table into its own Column. This fixed the error.